# cakephp comma separated ids as foreign id

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

How Can I use comma separated ids as foreign key in cakephp, my NursingHome Model has these ids of Specialization Model `NursingHome.specialization_ids=2,4,7` and I want there Respective Name using single query I am using this code:

```
class NursingHomeextends AppModel {
public 'hasMany' => array(
        'Specialization' => array(
           'className' => 'Specialization',
           'foreignKey' => false,
           'conditions' =>  'FIND_IN_SET(Specialization.id,NursingHome.specialization_ids)',
        ),
);
}
```

is there is any method to doing this?

Comment: It's a bad design because it's slow when confronted with a large volume of data.

Comment: Might be better off writing a quick script that pulls them all out and puts them into their own table(s).  To Mihai's point, it's not great design to do it the way you're asking.

Comment: OK thanks as you suggested I changed my db model, if you have any other method you can specify

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first need to make the array for ids.

```
$storIds = array(2,4,7);
```

Then you have 2 ways to execute this query.

**first:**

```
public 'hasMany' => array(
    'Specialization' => array(
       'className' => 'Specialization',
       'foreignKey' => false,
       'conditions' => 'FIND_IN_SET(\''. $storeIds .'\',Specialization.id)',
       )
    ),
);
```

**second**

```
'conditions' => array('Specialization.id' => $storIds)
```

Comment: Thanks but in this method I have to put ids from NursingHome.specialization_ids to an array first then I can use this method, so instead of one query I have to put two query for getting Names.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do the following:

```
$ListOfIds = new array(1,2,3,4);
```

And then use it in conditions like this

```
'conditions' => array('Specialization.id' => $ListOfIds)
```